# making a print button

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a button that would print my database in a contact list format. Where they would be grouped under the Departments that the contacts are added to on the php forms. Like this: (BELOW IS MY CODE FOR THE CONTACT PAGE)

```
                ADMIN
```

George George@snakdnasd 0282738292392
8432

```
             IT DEPARTMENT
```

Tyler tyler@askdnasdksan 7492823829292 8321

I have looked around and have tried the usual commands like window.print and just print() but it just prints the actual php page.

```
<?php 
require_once"connection.php";

$contacts = array();

$all_contacts = "select * from contacts where contact_status = '1'";


$sql_all_contacts = $conn->query($all_contacts);

$total_contacts = $sql_all_contacts->num_rows;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_all_contacts)) {
            $contacts[] = $row;
    }
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php include"includes/head.inc"; ?>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

    <!-- header section -->
    <?php include"includes/header.inc"; ?>

    <!-- content section -->
    <div class="content">
        <div class="floatl"><h1><?php echo $total_contacts ?> Contact(s) Total</h1></div>
                    <a class="floatr" href="insert_contact.php"><input class="cancel_contact_button" type="button" value="New Contact"></a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
            <hr class="pageTitle">
            <table border ="1" style="width:100%" id="contactsTable" class="display">
                <thead>
                    <tr align="left">
                        <th>Name:</th>
                        <th>Email:</th>
                        <th>Department:</th>
                        <th>Extension:</th>
                        <th>Cellphone:</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr> 
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($contacts as $contact) {?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $contact["name"];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $contact["email"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $contact["department"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $contact["extension"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $contact["cellphone"]; ?></td>
                        <td><a href="update_contact.php?id=<?php echo $contact["contact_id"]; ?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a> | <a href="delete_contact.php?id=<?php echo $contact["contact_id"] ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is `.inc` configure on your server? or also try without header .inc files

Comment: im still new to this so im not sure what how to configure.inc on my server?

Comment: first of all remove both .inc file and run your code... or is your file ext is .php or not??

Comment: it is .php but where would i find the .inc?

Comment: `<?php include"includes/head.inc"; ?>` and `<?php include"includes/header.inc"; ?>`

Comment: ok i removed it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122815/discussion-between-devpro-and-eternal-j).